# Is the MariaDB ODBC Connector 3.1.19 now stable for production when used with ASP Classic?

Tags: mariadb, odbc, asp-classic, connector

Has anyone used this driver successfully in a production environment?

Some time back I tried the MariaDB ODBC Connector 3.1.15 with a MariaDB 10.6 database; and the site kept crashing.

[image: ODBC driver setup 3.1.15]

I had to revert back to using the **MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver** to get the site stable.

I see in the MariaDB ODBC Connector 3.1.18 [release notes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-odbc-3-1-18-release-notes/) that there was a memory leak fix; and the driver had quite a few other bug fixes: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-odbc-31-release-notes/.

Is it production ready?

---

I updated the MariaDB ODBC Connector to 3.1.19 `mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.19-win64.msi` and will report back if it is still crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to MariaDB ODBC Connector to 3.1.19 and it fixed the crashing issue. (I also updated PHP.)